# elapsed time between node js application to connect with azure iot for sending data

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am using azure IOT for sending data to device using node js application.

Here is the package name for connecting to IOT - azure-iothub

Here is the method name to send DMI method -invokeDeviceMethodAsync(deviceID, params).then((result) => {});

When I send data to node js application to device via IOT, it is taking 1 - 2 sec for reaching data to device. So I need to understand where is the latency. When I checked in logs of IOT, it is transmitting data with in milliseconds. so, is it because of connecting node js application to IOT? OR Am i missing anything. Please suggest. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you specify more details ? When you say "it is taking 1-2" sec for reaching data, where are you checking this from ? device logs ? If yes then, are you using microsoft azure IoT Edge on the device?

Comment: I am generating timestamp before sending request to IOT and generating timestamp at device side, when it received data. Elapsed time between these two are always taking more than 1 sec. I want to decrease this to milliseconds. To your question about IOT Edge, I am not using IOT Edge device. It's normal IOT device